# Directus query: must equal the values

Tags: directus

I'm trying to call the API of Directus with the following statement:
I want all the items where the category.categories_id (not the ID of the collection categories) equals these values.

So I have a collection Items:

- Id
- Slug
- Short_description
- Long_description
- Image
- Status
- Categories
- Manufacturer

A table with the many to many relation Items_categories:

- Id
- Items_id
- Categories_id

And a collection Categories:

- Id
- Name
- Status

Imagine I have a item "Car1" with the categories_id 2 and 4 and a item "Car2" with the categories_id 1 and 4. When I filter the values 2 and 4 I only want the item "Car1".

These are the queries that I tried:

`<directus>/items/items?filter[categories][categories_id][_in]=2,4&fields=*,categories.*,manufacturer.name,manufacturer.id`

And I tried:

`<directus>/items/items?filter[categories][categories_id][_eq]=2,4&fields=*,categories.*,manufacturer.name,manufacturer.id`

This results in retrieving items that have 2 OR 4 as categories_id, but I want the items that have 2 AND 4.

I also saw the 'all' operator here: https://v8.docs.directus.io/api/query/filter.html, but it didn't returned the expected items.

Can anyone help me? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Are you sure this is related to `jQuery` ?

Comment: You're right, I changed the labels

Comment: This is for Directus 8 or Directus 9?

Comment: @RANGER Directus version 9.0.0

Comment: Directus 9's filter endpoint (https://docs.directus.io/reference/api/query/#filter) allows for specific AND/OR logical constraints (https://docs.directus.io/reference/filter-rules/). Have you tried using an explicit AND filter?